# Server thread hang

Tags: java, client-server

I use a thread to serve the client but when I remove the command `handler.out.flush` (on Server class), the thread hangs. I've tried searching on google but still not helping. I think the problem lies in the communications socket but I still have not got the right solution.

I want to make a simple login and registration functions so i used 2 class, `Server` and `MysqlConn`. The `Server` class receives incoming data (user profile - username, password, etc) from the client over the socket. After receiving, the data will be sent to `MysqlConn` class. The function of `MysqlConn` class is to check against the data and access my sql database to match them.  If data and database match, then login process is succsses.

The format of data sent by the client is:

```
"login."+"name."+ "password." +"\n";
```

The following is the contents of `Server` class:

```
public class Server {     

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, InstantiationException, 
IllegalAccessException {

    ServerSocket servsocket = null;
    Socket sock = null;         

    try {
        servsocket = new ServerSocket(28000);
        while(true){
        sock = servsocket.accept();
        System.out.println(servsocket.isBound());

        ChatThread thread = new ChatThread(sock); 
        String portnum = Integer.toString(sock.getPort());
        thread.run(portnum);                
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {

    } 
    finally{
            try {
                servsocket.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {

                }
            }       
    }
   } 

class ChatThread extends Thread{
    static Vector<ChatThread> chatthread = new Vector<ChatThread>(10);

    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;        

    public ChatThread (Socket socket) throws IOException {

        in  = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(
              new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())); }

    public void run(String portnum){
        String line;
        synchronized(chatthread) {
        chatthread.addElement(this); }
        try {
        line = in.readLine()+portnum;
        String[] teksmasuk = line.split("\\.");

        for(int i = 0; i < chatthread.size(); i++) {
                synchronized(chatthread) {
                ChatThread handler =
                (ChatThread)chatthread.elementAt(i);
                handler.out.println(line + "\r");
                handler.out.flush();
                if 
   (teksmasuk[0].contentEquals("reg")||teksmasuk[0].contentEquals("login")

    ||teksmasuk[0].contentEquals("logout")) {
                    if(teksmasuk[0].contentEquals("reg")){
                         }
                    else 
    if(teksmasuk[0].contentEquals("login")){
                         }

                MysqlConn sqlcon = new MysqlConn();
                String hasil = sqlcon.register(line);


                }                   
                else{           

                }
                }

                }           
        } catch(IOException ioe) {

        ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            synchronized(chatthread) {
            chatthread.removeElement(this);
            }
        }
 }                                              
}
```

`MysqlConn` class:

```
 public class MysqlConn{
String dbn = "chat_db";
 String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+dbn ;
 String usr = "root";
 String pwd = ""; 
 private String result;
 boolean checkname  = false;
 boolean checkemail     = false;
 boolean checkpass  = false;
 private Connection con = null;
private String dbnama;
private String dbpass;   

 public String register(String line) throws InstantiationException, 
 IllegalAccessException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

         String[] messagein = 
 line.split("\\.");

         MysqlConn regs = new MysqlConn();
         regs.login(messagein);
         return result;            
  }

  public void login (String[] messagein) throws InstantiationException, 
  IllegalAccessException{
     if(messagein[0].contentEquals("login")) {
         try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,usr,pwd);
             Statement statement = 
    con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
             ResultSet rslset = statement.executeQuery("select * from user"); 
             int rs = statement.executeUpdate("update user set port="+ 
    "'"+messagein[3] +"'" + "where nama  = " 
                     + "'" + messagein[1] + "'" + "and password = " + "'" 
   +messagein[2] +"'" );

             MysqlConn regs = new MysqlConn();
             regs.check_status_login(messagein);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Error #1:" + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(0);
            } catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.println("Error #2:" + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(0);
            }
      }
  }

  public void check_status_login (String[] messagein) throws InstantiationException, 
  IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException{
     try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,usr,pwd);
         Statement statement = 
    con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
         ResultSet rslset = statement.executeQuery("select * from user");              

         while(rslset.next()) {
             String dbname  = rslset.getString("nama");
             String dbpass = rslset.getString("password");                   
             if((messagein[1].contentEquals(dbnama))){

                 + messagein[1]+ "\r" + "Password from database: "+dbpass + "\r" + 
                 "Password from client: "+ messagein[2]+ "\n");
                 checknama = true;
             }
             else if (messagein[2].contentEquals(dbpass)){
                    checkpass = true;
             }
    }
         } catch (SQLException e1) {
         + e1);
    }
     if (!checknama){
         hasil = "gagal";
     }
     else if (!checkpass)
     {
         hasil = "gagal";
     }
     else {
         hasil = "login sukses";}
    }
   }
```

Comment: Call ChatThread.start() instead of run to actually start the thread. Calling run is a regular method that will not start the thread.

Comment: I've replaced it(**thread.run(portnum);** to **thread.start();**) but still error

Comment: There is just too much code here for us to parse and help you with.  I would make sure you are logging _all_ exceptions, and use a debugger or `println` messages to figure out where you are stuck.  Then you can trim down your code to the actual problem location.

Comment: and why are you using a vector over there.. If you want clients to communicate with each other eventually, maintain a list of threads in the main class and the main class should provide functionality to talk to others.. That way some of the complexity will be distributed away

Answer (score 0):

The java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) clearly say that the constructor you are using for PrintWriter will not cause automatic flushing. This means that you nead to call flush to send data out of the printwriter manually. Alternatively you can do

```
out = new PrintWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()) , true );
```

to enable automatic flushing. I generally prefer to do flush streams manually anyways.

As far as your question regarding your "application gets stuck" , you will need to provide more information such as how many clients connected and what exactly happens before the system hangs